# How to print horizontal lists in TableForm?

Tags: list-manipulation

How to print the table with the first column as $\{1,2,3\}$ instead of $\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\\end{array}$?

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, 1, 4, 9};
b = {{4, 6, 2}, 16, 36, 4};
TableForm[{a, b}]
```

> [image]

The aim would be to handle the following example:

```
c = Table[{{i, i + 1, i + 3}, i + 4, i + 5, N[1/i]}, {i, 1, 34}];
TableForm[c]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this it what you meant:

```
a = {HoldForm@{1, 2, 3}, 1, 4, 9};
b = {HoldForm@{4, 6, 2}, 16, 36, 4};
TableForm[{a, b}]
```

> [image]

If you have a bigger list (see [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/how-ro-print-horizontalle-lists-in-tableform/47314?noredirect=1#comment140338_47314)) you can do that:

```
c = Table[{{i, i + 1, i + 3}, i + 4, i + 5, N[1/i]}, {i, 1, 34}];
TableForm[Prepend[#[[2 ;;]], HoldForm@(Evaluate@First@#)] & /@ c]
```

Only the first `10` lines are shown bellow

[image]

Comment: Thank You, your solution is perfect!! but...  I put onli 2 lineas ( a and b) but I have 60 or 80 lines y a list history, where each line is on the estyle {{1,2,3},4,5,0.21212,6,6}  Could you edit with any sol to this case

Comment: PERFECT!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Shorter solution

```
c = Table[{{i, i + 1, i + 3}, i + 4, i + 5, N[1/i]}, {i, 1, 34}];
TableForm[c, TableDepth -> 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that as follows:

```
c = Table[{HoldForm@Evaluate[{i, i + 1, i + 3}], i + 4, i + 5, 
N[1/i]}, {i, 1, 34}] // TableForm
```